# Linear algebra, intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider: [image]

Now the first problems are quite simple with Gauss-Jordan, but in problem 50, I'm just not sure exactly what it is asking?

What does it mean to "describe points"? And if I write the problem like I think it is asking I get:

$x = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{matrix} \right) + s\cdot \left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{matrix} \right) + t \cdot \left( \begin{matrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right) $

But this gives me loads of variables..? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to parametrize the set of points. In order to do that, with the system that you wrote you have $a = s-2t +1$, $b=s-t+2$ and $c=-s+3$, therefore

$$S= \{ 
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {1}  \\
   {1}  \\
   {-1}  \\
\end{array}} \right)s
+
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {-2}  \\
   {-1}  \\
   {0}  \\
\end{array}} \right)t
+
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {1}  \\
   {2}  \\
   {3}  \\
\end{array}} \right)
\mid s,t \in \mathbb{R}
\}$$
where $S$ is the set of all points that fulfill the conditions.

Comment: Okay, guess it's that simple then. Thanks.